# will someone explain what this does in C / UNIX

Tags: c, unix, process, controls

```
pid_t fork(void);
```

I want to know what this command does in C.  Process Control.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork

Comment: fork() returns twice. Bend your mind around that.

Comment: Google is your friend...

Comment: @CharlieBurns to make up for that, `longjmp()` doesn't return at all ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates a child process which has a copy of the parent’s heap, stack and data space.
You need to `#include <unistd.h>`.  You could use this when you want a process to duplicate itself so that the parent and child can each execute different sections of code at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a fork in the road: you have one road until the point the road forks, then you have two roads which, for an instant, are identical (but then they diverge). `fork()` is the same thing for your program.